Label and legend placed out of the chart
I have a problem where the chart is properly rendered in Chrome browser but not in Brave or Safari. I have no clue what could be wrong. Are there some plotly.js options I can try out to make any difference?
OK - in Chrome
https://pasteboard.co/IyPErnaX7Xpk.png
NOT OK - in Safari and Brave
https://pasteboard.co/UbqO7lMRwHjP.png

You need to provide a mwe so we can at least reproduce the issue.
